# How can i fetch app store reviews published by application developer

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, rest, app-store

How can i fetch app store reviews published by application developer i.e. developer response on customer reviews rss through API call ?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this and i found that there is no api from apple yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can look into Apple Affiliate website, as they are providing API to fetch some of their products,

Link: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#lookup

Above link will help you to get some idea about accessing Appstore app. [Affiliates program](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/) is offered by Apple to access some of their products includes, apps, music, movie, TV shows, books etc...